# How to transform/map range/array with some function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm an excel newbie so it's possible there's an answer to this already and I just didn't know the right terms. I'm trying to transform a set of data and then use it in another formula, without using an intermediate column.

Right now I have a spreadsheet with 10 assets in column A and some score in column B. I want to calculate the percent of a portfolio that I would allocate to each asset, based on its score, but capped so that no asset can have more than 30% of the portfolio.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to impose this cap without using another column for score prime.

Given the score data in column B, I have column D, "Unadjusted Portfolio Percent", where each row has the formula `=B3/SUM($B$2:$B$11)`

I then have column E, with column B's values but capped at 30%, `=MIN(D2, 0.3)`.

Finally, I have column F "Adjusted Portfolio Percent", `=E2/SUM($E$2:$E$11)`.

**How do I do this without column E?**

My first instinct is that there's probably some syntax for applying a transformation to a column before using it, lambda style. I.e. in pseudocode the Adjusted Portfolio Percent column should be able to be calculated

```
let values = min(score / sum(scores), .3) / sum(adjusted) for score in scores
             where adjusted = min(score / sum(scores), .3) for score in scores
```

I have no clue how to do this with excel, though I'd be stoked if I could write a formula with some sort of lambda syntax. E.g. with scores in column B the 2nd row would be

`=MIN(B2/SUM($B:$B), .3)/SUM(x -> MIN(x/SUM($B:$B), .3), $B:$B)`.

Factoring out the repeated logic into a local function would be cool, but maybe that's a lot to ask of something that's not a programming language. Maybe this data transformation is a lot to ask of something that's not a programming language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to do it.

If say, 1 or 2 values are set to 30%, then the other values have to be scaled so they add to 70% or 40% etc.  This formula does that:

```
 =IF(C2>=0.3,0.3,(C2/(SUMIF(C$2:C$11,"<0.3")))*(1-0.3*(COUNTIF(C$2:C$11,">=.3"))))
```

[image]

John, Excel syntax can be obtuse, so let me walk you through this.  The IF() formula fills in one of two values depending on whether the % in column C is greater than or equal to 30%.  If it is, the formula returns 0.3.  If not, it returns the calculation in the rest of the formula.

The first part, C2/SUMIF(), gives the % that the value in column C represents of the values that are < 30%.  These percentages would sum to 100%, so they are multiplied by the second part, 1-0.3*COUNTIF().  It starts with 1 and subtracts .3 for each value >= 30%. So the values from the first part are scaled by a factor of 0.7, or 0.4, etc.

If it's possible to have more than 3 stocks > 30%, then some error checking is probably in order.  Hope this helps, and I enjoyed seeing your lambda expressions.

Comment: Great! Thank you for walking me through the syntax there—that's some real Excel wizardry!

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks to you too.  I think the key here is realizing that the values >= 30% put a constraint on the other values that makes it easy to find them.  The formula looks complicated only because of Excel's somewhat cumbersome syntax.  The lambda expression you wrote is much prettier.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to re-think you methodology slightly.  Consider:

[image]

In which column **B** are raw scores, column **C** are normalized versions of column **B**, column **D** are clipped versions of column **C**, and column **E** is the normalized version of column **D**.

The problem is an item like Ophelia.  Its normalized value exceeds 30%.  When it is limited and then re-normalized, its value **still** exceeds 30%.

Comment: This is quite a good point... You're absolutely right.